# C# DateTime.ParseExact 000+0000

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, datetime-format

I tried to find an answer in other forums or questions but I cannot find an answer to my problem

I trying to convert a string to DateTime

This is my string: `1999-12-31T23:00:00.000+0000`

I'm using this line (after trying a lot of options)

```
DateTime.ParseExact("1999-12-31T23:00:00.000+0000", "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss:000+ZZZZZ", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Thanks for helping me

Comment: That's an invalid offset. An offset in the ISO8601 format *must* be in the form `hh:mm`. You'll find several duplicates asking how to convert this *invalid* date but the only way is to split the string and parse the datetime and offset parts separately, or inject the missing `:`

Comment: [The docs explain how `z` behaves](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#offset-z-format-specifier). There can only be up to3 `z`s,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure, try this.

```
var str = "1999-12-31T23:00:00.000+0000";
var parts = str.Split('+');
var date = DateTime.Parse(parts[0]);
var offset = TimeSpan.Parse(parts[1]);
var dto = new DateTimeOffset(date, offset);
```